# Apple Screen Sharing

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

So I am very confused about the "Screen Sharing" feature on macOS (Ventura or Sonoma).

I can use the Apple built-in Screen Share App on my MacBook where it is possible to enter the Apple ID of someone else.

Does this only work in the same network or does it work no matter where the other person is located as long as I know the Apple ID (no port forwarding, etc.) that can be entered there in the text field within the app?

If I am not wrong when using the IP address instead of Apple ID it only works within the same network or if the other device on another network has port forwarding on its router there.

Was a bit worried that someone knowing my Apple ID could relatively easily connect from anywhere in the world to my MacBook by just opening the app and entering the Apple ID.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. We strongly prefer one question per question. Can you edit this to ask one question, the first one you need an answer. Then if that learn to one or three follow on questions, that’s encouraged to ask each as a single thread.  What’s the main thing you need to do now?

Comment: Specifically it’s possible you’re over estimating the remote capabilities of screen sharing. Are you [following this guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-the-screen-of-another-mac-mh14066/mac) or doing a share as part of a FaceTime video that’s already established?

Comment: I am refering to the screen sharing app which is part of macos. You can there connect to another macbook if that device has screensharing enabled by entering the ipadress shown on that device in the settings or via entering apple-id (Thats what i completely dont understand).

Comment: Aah, so that’s a very good clarification and edit. +1

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "There it is possible to enter an AppleID of someone else".?? There's no way Apple would let you access the screen of another Mac without authorisation, though for Macs with the same Apple ID, that may be transparent.

Comment: This is one Article regarding this question. The first part pretty mich describes it. My Question is simple (maybe someone has tried this already or knows the answer). Does this work if not in the same network? https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-screen-share-on-mac-remotely-locally/amp

Comment: Apple Screen Sharing is a largely non-conformant VNC client/server for macOS. Last I checked, most of its data is unencrypted, so it's a poor choice for serious usage. There are lots of SSH/SSL-enabled VNC options, and other commercial apps like Parallels Access offer better security and redirectors so you don't need to manage dynamic DNS and open ports into your network. Basically, Apple Screen Sharing is largely outdated and not secure for anything other than casual home usage, and maybe not even then.

Comment: Thank you, I read some other forum discussions. And yes normally it behaves like normal VNC so only locally within the same network via the ip or url. But some people stated that if you enter the apple-id (As you can see in the article I mentioned above) it takes another route and it could go remotely from wherever that person is. I am just worried someone knowing my apple-id could send out requests and stuff

Comment: Can you explain what the worry is here? Anybody knowing your AppleID can send you mail and messages, and they can also send screen sharing requests. But unless you accept those requests they won't be able to see your screen or do anything on your computer.

Comment: I am aware of that. I explained the worry further down in the thread to tetsujin.

Comment: Screen sharing only works if the request is manually accepted on the target Mac. So I'm not sure what is left here in term of security/privacy.

Comment: If it also has to be manually accepted if both devices are logged into the same apple-id then everything is clear and secure

Comment: Can you please focus your question on the actual problem you are trying to solve/prevent? From looking at the question text and the comments it seems to have evolved quite a bit.

Comment: The main question has been answered as it seems. You cant access another device via screen sharing outside of the same network without port forwarding on the router of the request receiving mac. Screen sharing via apple-id can go over different networks without router modification. And you always receive a request before screen sharing starts. So it evolved only to the final question if there is also a request to accept if the asking and receiving device are logged into the same apple-id

Answer (score 0):

Apple macOS screen sharing doesn't navigate NAT/firewall traversal or other items and I can't see any case where I'd enter my Apple ID on another computer even though the risk is low that there's a key logger or the password gets saved.

Since Apple doesn't broker connections off the local network, there's little value in signing in with your Apple ID on another computer.

You would want to get this tool that explicitly helps navigate connections across the internet. I've used it and it's very clear about how your password is used when a connection is unilateral (support/guided) and when it's remote, no prompt is needed.

- [Screens Express for macOS](https://edovia.com/en/screens-express/)
- [Screens Connect for Mac and Windows](https://edovia.com/en/screens-connect/)
- [Screens 4 for macOS](https://edovia.com/en/screens-mac/)

Comment: I am refering to the first part of this article (There are many more to explain the same steps). I am not that competent when it comes to tcip/ip and all of that so what do you mean by it does not navigate NAT/Firewall? Does that mean the connection goes via a server like for teamvier for example or is it not possible to watc my macbook screen outside of my network? Sorry if this sounds a bit confusing I am trying to understand the different ways on how someone could access my screen https://mbsdirect.com/mbs-blog/article-use-the-macrsquos-built-in-screen-sharing-to-provide-remote-help

Comment: Thanks @cami - NAT is how your home router and almost every other work / home network uses IP addresses that are not unique and therefore non-routable. No one can come to any home computer unless the "router" translates a request to its address (which is routable) on to your computer. That complicated task is what I refer to as "firewall traversal" or "navigate the firewall". Let me see if I can link to a better explanation and edit my answer...

Comment: The best I can explain is to download and try Screens Express - the steps involved in Firewall / NAT setup are all of the steps in this document - it's quite technical. https://help.edovia.com/en/screens-connect-4/how-to/reachable-without-screens-connect That's why Edovia makes software and charges money to make it easier to set up - they automate and test and provide guidance on your specific network when needed.

Comment: Thank you, that part I understand. I dont want to use screen sharing at all. I am worried that someone knowing my apple-id (Just mail is enough as it seems in the article i stated above?!) to send me requests to watch my screen. I read other threads in this forum where people said that if the sharing goes via apple-id in the screen sharing app then my firewall doesnt matter because apple creates the connection differently. Reading the article and those threads i became anxious now so do I have to worry in any way?

Comment: Empirically, Screen Sharing using AppleID **does** traverse NAT & hops happily through a remote consumer modem/router with zero config necessary, very much like TeamViewer & its ilk. I use it to do remote tasks on my octogenarian parents' iMac. *However*, it requires the remote Mac to allow you in. It pops a dialog requesting permission to connect. I've tested it to my own ID/account on that remote Mac but that doesn't work, only to my folks' ID. Of course, if Screen Sharing &/or Remote Management is off… there's no way in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights. So i understand it correct that screen sharing via apple-id is an exception and it bypasses NAT and works differently no matter where the other device is? Do I also understand it right that you have tested it with both devices being logged into the SAME apple-id and that did not work at all? Thats my main worry if my apple-id would be compromised and theoretically a mac somewhere is logged in with it would he be able to connect to me or not or would i have to accept at least... Very theoretical I know

Comment: I need to test @Tetsujin Back to My Mac is back again! Exciting and my answer needs major change to the first parts

Comment: @bmike - I can't get to my own AppleID on that Mac that way; even though it is registered on the folk's Mac [though probably not currently on or logged in] nor does that Mac show on FindMy. It's not something I've really tested extensively. Until quite recently I had a corporate gateway here which nothing could punch through, but now I've a regular ISP modem/router which is much easier, with UPnP etc. During that period I've been almost exclusively at home, so haven't been able to test if I could get into my own desktop from a remote MBP etc. It's one I marked down as 'needs further research'.

Comment: I really did have hopes for it being another way to get Back to my Mac functionality going again. BTW, one additional cool thing is, as it connects to the far Mac, it enables both mics so you can talk.

Comment: So even if both macs would be logged in with the same apple-id I would receive a request on the receiving mac before the sharing starts via Apple-ID in the screen sharing app? It would never auto connect